# How can I let fruit ripen faster?

Tags: vegetables, fruit, ripe

In addition to specific fruits like [avocados](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/89/what-can-i-do-to-help-my-avocados-ripen) and [bananas](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/12014/is-it-scientifically-verified-that-bananas-will-ripen-faster-when-kept-in-a-bowl), and the specific trick of [using a brown bag](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/109/why-does-a-brown-paper-bag-speed-ripening), I would like to know if there are ways to let fruit and vegetables in general ripen faster. Are all fruits the same, or is it different for every kind of fruit/vegetable? If there is some general way or mechanism, what methods generally work to expedite fruit ripening?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it scientifically verified that bananas will ripen faster when kept in a bowl with other fruit?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/12014/is-it-scientifically-verified-that-bananas-will-ripen-faster-when-kept-in-a-bowl)

Comment: But there can be some other ways to?

Comment: Well, it doesn't need to be a banana. It's just the ethylene you need. You can use an apple, tomato... See http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/109/why-does-a-brown-paper-bag-speed-ripening for more information.

Comment: @Mien , feel free to see if this edit reframes the question effectively to make the `duplicates` into `relateds`; @lotte, I have edited your question pretty heavily, but I don't think that I have changed the substance of your question. If you feel I have, feel free to roll it back.

Comment: @mfg sure :) Also, this is related as well: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/154/how-do-i-ripen-unripe-oranges-and-grapefruits

Answer (score 5):

As I was explaining in my answer to [this question about figs](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/23237/what-to-do-with-under-ripe-figs) the "brown bag" trick, works for any [climacteric fruit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climacteric_fruits).

A list of some climacteric and non-climacteric fruits can be found [here](http://www.quisqualis.com/Climacteric.html).

It is important to note that some non-climacteric fruits (such as bell peppers or strawberries) will not respond to an ethylene treatment at all, and will not ripen further after being picked from the plant. Other fruits (such as citrus and grapes) will show ripening responses to ethylene, although they do not have an auto-catalytic production of this molecule<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup>[Ripening of citrus and other non-climacteric fruits: a role for ethylene](http://www.actahort.org/members/showpdf?booknrarnr=463_42)

Answer (score 0):

Avocados ripen in about 3 days (from rock hard) in a sack of flour vs up to a week sitting out.

Covering completely in flour has the advantage of preventing pressure bruises.

Forgetting them for a month can be icky...